# Wildcard syntax in Cons cell implementation in Streams.scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

```
/** A lazy cons cell, from which streams are built. */
  @SerialVersionUID(-602202424901551803L)
  final class Cons[+A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A] with Serializable {
    override def isEmpty = false
    override def head = hd
    @volatile private[this] var tlVal: Stream[A] = _
    def tailDefined: Boolean = tlVal ne null
    override def tail: Stream[A] = {
      if (!tailDefined)
        synchronized {
          if (!tailDefined) tlVal = tl
        }

      tlVal
    }
  }
```

What does the wildcard `_` represent in `@volatile private[this] var tlVal: Stream[A] = _`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard assigns a default value to a `var`, which makes the variable initialized and ready for use; As far as I know, that is going to be `null` for anything descending from `AnyRef` and a 'default' value for `AnyVal`s (`0` for numbers, `false` for `Boolean` etc.).

You can't have declared, but undefined local variables. Example speaks volumes:

```
scala> var a : Int = _
a: Int = 0

scala> var b : String = _
b: String = null

scala> var bool : Boolean = _
bool: Boolean = false

scala> var c : Long
<console>:7: error: only classes can have declared but undefined members
(Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined)
       var c : Long
```